# sidekiq not starting with mina deployment of rails 4 app.

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a rails 4.2 application which uses sidekiq. I am using mina for deployment. My Gemfile contains 'sidekiq' and 'mina-sidekiq'.

My deployment script is as

```
require 'mina_sidekiq/tasks'                                                                                                                              
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rvm'    # for rvm support. (http://rvm.io)

set :domain, 'x.x.x.x'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/appname'
set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/appname.git'
#set :identity_file, "#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/id_rsa"
set :branch, 'master'
set :rails_env, 'production'

set :shared_paths, ['config/secrets.yml', 'log', 'tmp']
set :user, 'deploy'

task :environment do 
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-2.2.1@default]'
end

task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/tmp"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/tmp"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/tmp/pids"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/tmp/pids"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"]                                                                                        
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit '#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml'."]
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
  task :deploy => :environment do
  to :before_hook do
    # Put things to run locally before ssh
  end
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'sidekiq:quiet'
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    to :launch do
      queue "mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/"
      queue "touch #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
      invoke :'sidekiq:restart'
    end
  end                                                                                                                                                     
end
```

config/sidekiq.yml contains

```
# Sample configuration file for Sidekiq.                                                                                                                  
# # Options here can still be overridden by cmd line args.
# # sidekiq -C config.yml
# ---
:verbose: false
:concurrency: 1
:queues:
  - [often, 7]
  - [default, 5]
  - [seldom, 3]
```

the last few contains of 'mina deploy --verbose' are as

```
-----> Build finished

-----> Moving build to releases/37
   $ mv "$build_path" "$release_path" 

-----> Updating the current symlink
   $ ln -nfs "$release_path" "current" 

-----> Launching
   $ cd "$release_path" 

-----> Stop sidekiq
   Skip stopping sidekiq (no pid file found) 

-----> Start sidekiq
   $ bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production -C  /home/deploy/appname/current/config/sidekiq.yml -i 0 -P /home/deploy/appname/shared/pids/sideki       
   $ bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production -C /home/deploy/appname/current/config/sidekiq.yml -i 0 -P /home/deploy/appname/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid -L /home/deploy/appname/current/log/sidekiq.log

-----> Done. Deployed v37
```

The problem is that sidekiq process is still not running on the server after deployment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

On your production instance.Please check, Is there sidekiq.log file exists or not. if exists then please have a look on logs in this file.

```
/your_app_name/current/log$ sudo nano sidekiq.log
```

Is redis server running in your instance ?
To Bind redis server with sidekiq

Make a file config/redis.yml . Write the below code -

```
development:
     host: 'localhost'
     port: '6379'

test:
    host: 'localhost'
    port: '6379'

production:
    host: 'your_app_name-cache.name.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com'
    port: '6379'
```

Make sure there must be an instance elasticache on server and a custom tcp  rule should be added in inbound in security groups of particular cache instance.